# Date field of my table not being read correctly from a mysql database inside R

Tags: r, dplyr, rmysql

I am using `RMySQL` to query a database (example name `my_data` )
I am using `src_mysql`. along with the `tbl` function from R `dplyr`

I want to query a transaction table (example name `trans_table`) from within `my_data`.
My `trans_table` has  a field named `Transaction_Date` Inside `MySQL`,
I can see that `Transaction_Date` has a column type of date.

I used the following approach

```
# set up MySQL connection and use dplyr henceforth
MySQLconnection <- src_mysql(dbname = "my_data", 
                         user = "username", 
                         password = "XXXX", 
                         host = "host_name")
```

This was successful. Then I wrote

```
trans_table_R <- tbl(MySQLconnection, "trans_table")
```

The above also ran successfully. However when I run the below query

```
trans_table_R %>% filter(between(trans_date, "2016-04-01", "2016-04-10"))
```

my output shows `trans_date` as a character column.

I also wanted to make an additional point. After running the `tbl` statement
If I inspect `trans_table_R` to see the 10 rows, I get `warnings` from `R` saying that decimal columns from the table are imported as numeric.
Can this warning be ignored ?

**I cannot provide a snapshot of the error since I am not permitted to do so**.
However, I wanted to know what exactly could be the problem
and what is a workaround